# Flutter and Firebase: Is there a way to run a function on each data snapshot before they are displayed?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My aim is to run a decrypt function on the data from firebase before it is displayed to the user.

[Here is the database layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHcRI.png)

Here is the widget displaying the data:

```
Widget buildPatientCard(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {

  final patient = Patient.fromSnapshot(document);

  return new Container(
  child: Card(
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                Text(patient.name,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Spacer(),
                Text(patient.gender,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(", ",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(patient.age,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              ]),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 80.0),
              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                Text(patient.dob,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Spacer(),
              ]),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  patient.notes,
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Icon(Icons.person),
```

Here is the patient model:

```
Patient.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot):
patientId = snapshot.documentID,
  name = snapshot['Patient name'],
  gender = snapshot['Gender'],
  age = snapshot['Age'],
  dob = snapshot['Date of Birth'],
  notes = snapshot['Notes'];
```

Here is the decrypt function I want to run on each of the data snapshots before they are displayed:

```
  _decrypt() async {
var userKey = await getUserKey();

final decryptedText =
    await FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString(DATA FROM FIREBASE HERE, userKey);
return decryptedText;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this working through trial and ERRORS! It doesn't seem like it's the most efficient way (we shall worry about that later), but at-least for now it's working.

First I created a function that would decrypt the patient information using the snapshot and the user key, like so:

```
 Future<String> _decryptName() async {
  var userKey = await getUserKey();
  String decryptText =
      await FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString(patient.name, userKey);
  return decryptText;
}
```

I then used a FutureBuilder to wait on the function and build the snapshot, like so:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _decryptName(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.hasData)
    return Text(
     '${snapshot.data}',
       style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
   if (snapshot.error)
    return Text(
     'Error getting the data.',
       style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 7.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
         return const CircularProgressIndicator();
   }),
```

Like I said - this doesn't seem like the most efficient approach, so if anyone finds a better way be sure to let me know.